# How to apply the .change function on the field which is created b the .change function of some other field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is creating a process name(prc) field on changing part no(pno) field, now i want the process characteristic field on changing process name but .change function on process name is not working($('#prc').change(function(){}); this function is not working)

```
 $('#pno').change(function(){
   var partno=$("#pno option:selected" ).val();
   $.ajax({ 
       cache: false,
       dataType: "html",
       type: "POST", 
       evalScripts: true,
       url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addpro'));?>',
       data: ({partno:partno}), 
       success: function(result){
         var pch=result.split('//');
         var plen=pch.length;
         var str="";
         $('#fid').html('');        
         str='<tr><td><br><b>PROCESS NAME</b><br><br></td></tr><tr><td><select name="process_name" label="" id="prc" style="height:30px; margin-top:-5px; min-width:190px; width:auto;" ><option value="">Select any</option>';
         $.each(pch,function(i,v){
           str += '<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>';
         });
        str +='</select></td></tr>';
        $('#fid').append(str);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: use $(document).ready(function(){ $('#prc').change(function(){}); });

Comment: this function is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to add the event listener directly after this line:

```
$('#fid').append(str);
```

when the node is ready to have event listeners attached, or you need to delegate the event from a parent node that is available before your new `<select>` is written to the DOM.

```
$('#fid').on('change', '#prc', function() {
   // do your stuff
});
```

This works by attaching the event to a valid component, but only firing when the selector of the changed element (beneath #fid) matches the selector '#prc'

Comment: Awesome, glad to help :) @shiprasharma

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the on function on dynamic fields.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried this code but this is also not working:$('#prc').on("change",function(){
  alert('yes');
});

Comment: @shipra sharma you have to use $('body').on('change', '#prc', function() {
   // do your stuff
});